# How to guarantee code in promise runs first in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
function f() {
  setTimeout(()=> {
    console.log(1);
  });

  // real situation
  // fetch(...).then(()=>{
  //   console.log(1);
  // });
}

function g() {
  console.log(2);
}

f();
g();
```

The actual output is 2, and then 1. Is there any way to guarantee 1, and then 2. Imagine `f` is a function from other people or a library that I have little control.

My real application is I want to guarantee my code runs after code in a promise in a function is run.

Comment: so ... where's the Promise you mention in the title?

Comment: `Imagine f is a function from other people or a library that I have little control.` - if it returns a Promise, then the solution is easy ... [use the Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises)

Comment: https://javascript.info/async-await

Comment: your example is strange, timeout callback will run in next cycle in any way. If you want to run your function after timeout, pass it as callback and call. This is the only thing i can say lookin on your example

Comment: Think the setTimeout as a promise. They don't return any promise to me, their code runs in a promise callback in their function.

Comment: @JaromandaX Async/await was implemented to make these things easier

Comment: if you not control what f() function does - you can know when it finish but you cant know when finished all async jobs that this function started

Comment: @VladimirGordienko that's right. I feel that's the point.

Comment: If `f` doesn't return anything and you can't change `f` it's probably impossible. For your simplified example with `setTimeout` there could be a solution to get a list of all timeouts and wait for them.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I feel so. So sounds like I have to poll if some flag is set, in reality the code in the promise sets some flags that I can access from outside.

Comment: You could redefine `f` to return a promise.

Comment: I wish I could. But it's not entirely impossible, unless I try to change other people's code.

Comment: You don't have to change other people's code. You have to partially copy and edit other people's code. You don't change `f`. You copy the definition of `f` and add the changes.

Comment: @ThomasSablik - async/await is not a replacement for working with Promises in every case

Comment: @JaromandaX But it's applicable in this case as you can see in the answer. I've never seen such a special case where promise handling can't be replaced by async/await. However, I suppose there are such cases. The alternative to `await f(); g();` is `f().then(g);`. I like the first one.

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah, I was once believe that async/await could replace Promise, but in this case, it seems it cannot.

Comment: @ThomasSablik `it's applicable in this case` - as long as you don't want to run f() and g() directly in the global context without creating a function, of course

Answer (score 1):

```
function f() {
 return new Promise(resolve => {
     resolve(1)     
  }).then(value=>{
      console.log(value)
  })
 }

function g() {
   console.log(2);
}

const run = async () => {
   await f();
   g();
}

run();
```

Comment: What if I cannot change f?

Comment: what do you mean by that? you mean you need to maintain that setTimeout function?

Comment: I've updated my code. The setTimeout is just to simulate the code runs in a promise's call back.

Comment: fetch is asynchronous as well, so it will behave the same